# Check file exists in directory with prefix of file name in Swift

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I want to check whether my File is exist with just prefix of file name in SWIFT.

E.g

My file name is  like Companies_12344

So after _ values are dynamic but "Companies_" is static.

How can i do that?

I have already done split filename code below

How can i check through NSFileManager for is exist file name with "Companies_"

### My code below For split

```
 func splitFilename(str: String) -> (name: String, ext: String)? {
    if let rDotIdx = find(reverse(str), "_")
    {
        let dotIdx = advance(str.endIndex, -rDotIdx)
        let fname = str[str.startIndex..<advance(dotIdx, -1)]
        println("splitFilename >> Split File Name >>\(fname)")
    }


    return nil
}
```

Comment: For the split you can just do str.componentsSeparatedByString("_")

Comment: yes that's fine...But with that prefix name how can i check if the file is exist or not from NSFileManager?

Comment: Where is the difference to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295161/check-filename-is-exist-by-prefix-in-swift ?

Comment: Martin, previous one was about the file name to be split and it was a bit confusing.. So I have added it more precisely this time NSFIlemanager...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code you need:

```
let str = "Companies_12344"

if str.hasPrefix("Companies") {
    println("Yes, this one has 'Companies' as a prefix")
    let compos = str.componentsSeparatedByString("_")
    if let file = compos.first {

        println("There was a code after the prefix: \(file)")
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

        var yourPath = paths.stringByAppendingPathComponent("\(file)_")

        var checkValidation = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        if (checkValidation.fileExistsAtPath(yourPath))
        {
            println("FILE AVAILABLE");
        }
        else
        {
            println("FILE NOT AVAILABLE");
        }
    }
}
```